# Google Analytics working intermittently

Tags: mobile, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have event tracking set up for a mobile adaptive site with Google Analytics.
However, GA event tracking appears to be working intermittently.
At the same time, GA has warned that the event tracking has "high cardinality".
Are these issues likely to be linked?

Thank you,

Simon

Comment: Yes, high cardinality dimensions are dangerous as they may hide a specific value from you.

http://www.internetrix.com.au/blog/google-analytics-high-cardinality-dimension-warning-is-dangerous/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, very possible. See this article on "high-cardinality" dimensions. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009671?hl=en

"When you view a report with a high-cardinality dimension that exceeds the above limits, you won't see all of the values for that dimension because some values are rolled-up into an (other) entry."

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks nyuen. However, my understanding is that the pixel is returned but categorised incorrectly (in other).